# What is the viscous component in viscoelastic materials?

Tags: materials, plastics, viscosity

All real solid materials are in certain way viscoelastic, because an ideal fully elastic material doesn't exist as well as a fully viscous solid material. According to rheologic models it is possible to define approximately the deformation of the material under stress.
I was searching information, but I don't know yet what is the cause of the viscosity.

For example this is the rheologic Tuckett model, which clearly shows the viscoelasticity of a real material (specifically a polymeric material)

[image]

An ideal elastic material after stress release would return to its original shape, but in a viscoelastic one, energy dissipation occurs and the material has not the sufficient energy to come back to its original shape (plastic deformation is resulted)

Here is the example of a ideal elastic material, where all the energy returns and the material takes back its shape and note, that the deformation response to the stress is immediate. On the other hand the viscoelastic materials have a late reaction to stress (why?).

[image]

The issue at stake is:

- what does it mean "when a material is more viscous than another one" and what is the cause of the viscous component in solid material?
  Viscosity in liquids is caused by friction of the particles during movement. Surely it is not possible to apply the same answer to the viscosity in viscoelastic materials.

Thank you in advance for helpfulness

Comment: The Wiki section on viscoelastic materials says "Viscoelastic materials have elements of both of these properties and, as such, exhibit time-dependent strain. Whereas elasticity is usually the result of bond stretching along crystallographic planes in an ordered solid, viscosity is the result of the diffusion of atoms or molecules inside an amorphous material"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are viscoelastic materials to be considered solids or fluids?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94747/are-viscoelastic-materials-to-be-considered-solids-or-fluids)

Comment: Check "rheologic mastercurve".